# Do we know anything about the mortal life of Bobby Dollar?

Tags: tad-williams, bobby-dollar-trilogy

In the Tad Williams series about the angel Doloriel, AKA Bobby Dollar, we know that grunt-level angels (like Bobby) are former (that means - deceased) humans. But contrary to those sent to Hell, those newly made angels have their memory wiped clean.

But in the last tome - *Sleeping late on Judgement Day* - during a fight with a very powerful entity, Bobby has a strange flashback:

> [...]I experienced other things too, things that were part of me but not part of me. Visions more real than any of my other memories [...]
> *Dust swirling, and sky and sun lancing down through it. Fallen rubble. More dust. Something heavy, pressing me down, trying to stop my heart. A woman's face, not [redacted], far more human, smeared in dust and dirt-caked blood, eyes half-closed. And distantly, the cry of a child, the hopeless, hitching wail of a child who cannot be comforted.*

And much later

> [...] Why - I said - Why to get to so much trouble to frame me?
> Frame You? You have not been accused of half what you have done! You spoiled so much! Even when you were alive, you were a thorn in my side!

This seems like memories of his mortal life, maybe the moment of his death.

Do we know anything else about Bobby's past? If not from the book, then maybe from the author himself? Maybe the scene above was from some other Tad Williams story? Was there a story about someone fighting against a Persian goddess?

Comment: Although I've yet to finish this series myself, I can't find any other data where the author has gone on record about it, and it does seem like that was the intended last book.  None of his other works seem like likely crossovers.  Unfortunately, a fate of a building collapsing on multiple people is not uncommon in recent decades, so it's not a very strong lead.